# rvest - scrape tripadvisor - FULL review text

Tags: r, dplyr, rvest

I am successfully scraping reviews from **tripadvisor** using **rvest**.

However, I am only scraping partial reviews and the full reviews would give my study more power.

What's needed is to get beyond the "MORE". I am not experienced in coding and source code so making the necessary modifications to my code is proving hard. 
Example: 2nd review on [this page](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g303855-d7159724-Reviews-Mangrove_Beach-Nabq_Bay_Sharm_El_Sheikh_South_Sinai_Red_Sea_and_Sinai.html)

```
review <- reviews %>%
html_node(".entry .partial_entry") %>%
html_text()
```

I can see the differences in the source code but not sure how to reflect that in R.

Here the differences

[image]

[image]

Thank you for advice and assistance.

Comment: This is against tripadvisor's  [terms of service](https://www.tripadvisor.com/pages/terms.html).

Comment: TripAdvisor has a link within their help service which allows you to request such permission. Here you detail what you will do and they consider whether to grant permission.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "MORE" is just a hidden DIV tag which becomes visible on clicking using JS. In such a case, your rvest code would have worked.

However, what you are referring to is a dynamic page. In such a case, it is better if your code emulates a web browser. For this, try RSelenium. Ample articles and videos are available if you search on web.

All the best!

Comment: Thank you Ajeet. Can I combine the use of rvest and RSelenium  in the same code? rvest is working perfectly for all other aspects so I am hesitant to rewrite everything. Also, do you know if the rvest submit_form could be used to achieve the rest of the review? Thank you sincerely for your response. I am new to this.